# A Gaussian as a mixture of two Gaussians

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm quite convinced that a mixture of two Gaussians is itself a Gaussian iff mean and variance  all equal :

$N(x,\mu_0,\sigma_0) = aN(x,\mu_1, \sigma_1) + (1-a)N(x,\mu_2, \sigma_2) \iff \mu_0 = \mu_1 = \mu_2 ; \sigma_0 = \sigma_1 = \sigma_2$

However I have a hard time proving it. I believe there's probably an easy "linear independence" argument, but my algebra is old.

Question is : how do I prove this?

Comment: Please explain -1. If it's for triviality, then please provide a trivial proof. If it's for bad tagging, feel free to add tags.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a a random variable following a mixture distribution that is a convex combination of two Gaussians with identical means and variances. This means that the density function of $X$ will be

$$f_x(x) = a\frac 1\sigma \phi\left(\frac {x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) + (1-a)\frac 1\sigma \phi\left(\frac {x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \frac 1\sigma \phi\left(\frac {x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

where $\phi()$ denotes the standard normal pdf. So indeed $X$ is just a Gaussian random variable - but this is an uninteresting case of "mixture" -in essence, it is not a mixture at all, since the mixture distributions are identical by design.

For the other direction, since the normal distribution is completely characterized by its mean and variance, then given three identical normals, any one of them can be trivially considered to be a mixture of the other two.

**ADDENDUM**
To further respond to user @RahulNarain comments, assume that the following holds:

$$af_1\left((x-\mu_1)/\sigma_1\right) + (1-a)f_2\left((x-\mu_2)/\sigma_2\right) = f_3\left((x-\mu_3)/\sigma_3\right) \qquad [1]$$

where the $f$'s are gaussian densities. Now, since these are densities on the same support, they must necessarily cross. Assume that at point $x^*$ the density $f_2$ crosses (equals) density $f_3$, 
$$f_2\left((x^*-\mu_2)/\sigma_2\right) = f_3\left((x^*-\mu_3)/\sigma_3\right)$$ 
It is evident from $eq. [1]$, that we must also have

$$f_1\left((x^*-\mu_1)/\sigma_1\right) = f_2\left((x^*-\mu_2)/\sigma_2\right)$$ 
and so the three densities are equal at point $x^*$.

$$f_1\left((x^*-\mu_1)/\sigma_1\right) = f_2\left((x^*-\mu_2)/\sigma_2\right) =f_3\left((x^*-\mu_3)/\sigma_3\right) \qquad [2]$$

Now the gaussian density is symmetric around its mean. So we have

$$f_i\left((-x^*+\mu_i)/\sigma_i\right) = f_i\left((x^*-\mu_i)/\sigma_i\right),\; i=1,2,3 \qquad [3]$$

Then combining with $[2]$ for this value too the three densities will be equal:

$$f_1\left((-x^*+\mu_1)/\sigma_1\right) = f_2\left((-x^*+\mu_2)/\sigma_2\right)=f_3\left((-x^*+\mu_3)/\sigma_3\right) \qquad [4]$$

From $[2]$ and $[4]$ we see that we must have various pairwise equalities *between* the densities, like, for example,

$$f_1\left((x^*-\mu_1)/\sigma_1\right) = f_3\left((-x^*+\mu_3)/\sigma_3\right)$$

But the only way that such pairwise equalities can hold, is if the means are equal, because
$x^*$ must have equal distance from each mean $|x^*-\mu_i|=|-x^*+\mu_i|,\;\; i=1,2,3$. So we conclude that for $[1]$ to hold we must have $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu_3=\mu$.

So the three densities will have the same mode $x=\mu$. Still, assume that their variances are different. Then, moving rightwards from the mode  we know that each must cross the other two  at two points. But since when the densities cross, we have seen that they must cross all three together. Now given the fact that $f_3$ is a linear combination of the other two, and its graph must always lie in the middle, and given the known curvature properties of the normal density, this is not possible (i.e to cross twice, cross all three at the same two points, have $f_3$ in the middle, and have the normal density curvature). So we conclude that their variances cannot be different, and therefore, for eq. $[1]$ to hold, all three must be identical.

Comment: I believe the question is to prove both directions of the implication.

Comment: @RahulNarain Done, although it, too, is trivial.

Comment: The reverse implication is that if the mixture of two Gaussians is a Gaussian, then all three Gaussians must be identical. This is not as trivial as showing that if three Gaussians are identical, then the mixture of two of them is the third.

Comment: @RahulNarain I added that too. I will admit it was a bit lengthy, but still, only very basic properties are needed.